# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uniqueId is not a function when using a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I've already used a `jquery` plugin for photo zoom [imgViewer2](https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer2)

when I add that to my `vue js` project, I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uniqueId is not a function

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/issues/94

Comment: you have jquery UI running? What versions?

Comment: i see that question. this is not that i want . i use jquery 3.2.1

Comment: Have you imported your jQuery library *before* the vue.js scripts?

Comment: yes yes. my jquery is already imported

Comment: Just to be sure try to `console.log($)` so that you can be sure it's loaded properly

Comment: Also it looks like there is an analogue of this plugin in Vuejs https://github.com/mirari/v-viewer

Comment: yes dadash .i actually sure that jquery loaded properly

Comment: Did you not only import jQuery but also jQuery UI? This library has 3 dependencies: https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer2/blob/master/plugindocs/usage.md